# jQuery - keyup event as function

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, click, key

I found this example of use **keyup** event:

```
$(document).keyup(function(e) {

  if (e.keyCode == 27) { 
    //ESC
  }   

});
```

This works me, but I am trying to edit this part of code for function, something like this:

```
$(function() {
    $('a.this_page').live('click', function () {  
      //simple function - after click on the link will make some action
    });
});
```

And I am trying to update the first part of code to the second part of code - I would like to do an action from the second example with **click** on the link and also after press some key... but I am not sure, how to do..

Could anyone help me, please, how to make it?
Thank you.

Comment: Can you tell us the overall aim, do you want to have special functionality that works when the user clicks the mouse while holding a key, or should the keypress happen after the click, before the click? Or should it work with either a click or a keypress?

Comment: I would like my "action" work if the user click on the link OR if he click on the key (keypress)

Answer (score 2):

You could use `bind()`:

```
$('body').bind('keyup click',
               function(e){
                   // stuff to do on 'click' and 'keyup' happens in here...
                   alert('woo! A : ' + e.type + ' happened!');
               });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/uxkdB/1/).

The above demo, obviously (I suppose...) assumes that you want the same thing(s) to happen on the `keyup` and `click` events.

References:

- [`bind()`](http://api.jquery.com/bind).
- [`e.type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Event.type).

Comment: thank you, but here is a bit problem - because - I am on the page, and if the user will press the button (for example ENTER), so I would like to do some action, and the the user will click on the link with special ID, so will be doing the same action, as above - I don't know, how to distinguish

Comment: You want to trigger the actions only if a particular element is clicked?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to do following - my basic functionality is - I have on one of my pages `<a href="bla bla" class="this_page">..</a>` - if I will click on this link, so I want to do the action from my post (this works me). And now I would like to add the second functionality - if I am on the page, where is `<a href="bla bla" class="this_page">..</a>`, so except click on this link and make something I would like to run the action from my post after the user pressed some key

Answer (score 0):

You will have to name the function and set it as event handler for both events, eg:

```
$(function () {
  function handleAction () {
    // do something
  }
  $(document).keyup(handleAction);
  $('a').live('click', handleAction);
});
```

Comment: There is no need for global function like this.